# Обязательны поля в моделях на Django

Tags: python, django

подскажите, как сделать поля в models.py обязательными для заполнения на Django? Пишу на python api приложение.

Comment: Мы не видим вашего файла `models.py`. Покажите его и мы постараемся вам помочь.

Answer (score 0):

Ознакомьтесь с [документацией](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#blank) получше.

- Если вы явно не указываете значение `blank`, то оно приравнивается к
  `False`.
- Если поле имеет значение `blank=False`, то оно будет
  обязательным для заполнения.
- Если поле имеет значение `blank=True`,
  то проверка формы позволит ввести пустое значение.